# Transformations of RV's Ensuring Absolute Continuity of Quantile Functions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, transformation

Given a real random variable $X$, suppose $T:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
  is non-decreasing. Define $Y=T\left(X\right)$.

Let $Q_{X}$, $Q_{Y}$ be the corresponding right-continuous quantile functions.

Let $\mu_{X},\mu_{Y}:\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\to\left[0,\infty\right)$
  be the measures induced by $Q_{X},Q_{Y}$,
  respectively, via the extension to a Borel measure of $$\mu_{X} :(a,b] \to [Q_{X}(b)-Q_{X}(a)]$$
  defined for all half-open intervals $\left(a,b\right]$. These are called *Stieltjes measures*.

**1. What is an equivalent condition for $\mu_{Y}$
  to be absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mu_{X}$?**

**2. Under the previous sufficient and necessary condition, is there always a closed form solution for the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d\mu_{Y}}{d\mu_{X}}$?**

*Context:*

An alternative characterization of the right-continuous quantile function is as a right-continuous generalized inverse to the distribution function of $X$.

**1.** I know that continuity of $T$
  would suffice but I don't know whether you can weaken this condition or not. Specifically it can be shown that $Q_{Y}=T\circ Q_{X}$
  even for right-continuous $T$
  but with only right-continuity there can be contradictions to the absolute continuity of $\mu_{Y}$
  w.r.t $\mu_{X}$

**2.** I know that if one assume $Q_{X}$
  is absolutely continuous and $T$
  is continuous then it is not very hard to get that $\frac{d\mu_{x}}{d\mu_{Y}}=T^{'}\circ Q_{X}$
  where $T^{'}$
  is the a.e derivative of $T$
 . However I'm not sure if this is still true if one forgoes the assumption that $Q_{X}$
  is absolutely continuous.